# How to pass parameters to spring data repository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-data

Consider this code:

```
    public interface AppRepository extends MongoRepository<App, String> {
    List<App> findAppsByUserAndIsDraft(String user, false);
}
```

I need to find all records by username and IsDraft. As you can see I am passing a `false` for IsDraft. This does not work as spring gives this error `identifyer or type expected`. Is there a way around this?

Comment: try with findAppsByUserAndIsDraft(String user, Boolean value);

Comment: @e.g78 i tried but still didnt work

Comment: findByUserAndIsDraftFalse(String user) should work as explained in table 3 of https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/data-jpa/docs/current/reference/html/#jpa.query-methods.named-queries. If it doesn't work, try removing "is" from the name of your attribute. "IS" is a keyword

Comment: Is the name of App's field "draft" or "isDraft"?

Comment: @TheGilbertArenasDagger its isDraft

Comment: Is that a copy/paste of your code?  Because if it is, then that's an invalid method declaration.  Instead of findAppsByUserAndIsDraft(String user, false) it should be findAppsByUserAndIsDraft(String user, boolean isDraft).  The other part that I noticed is that you used User and username... I'm assuming that's just an inconsistency in your question and that App's field is a String named user.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

List findAppsByUserAndIsDraft(String user, false);
change your method to 
List findAppsByUserAndIsDraftFalse(String user);